# Reading whitespace in heading of csv file using pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas

I need to read the heading from csv that have white between them, I need help to fix it. I try differnet way like delimiter = ' ' and delim_whitespace = True. Here is how I'm write the code:

> ```
> df = pd.read_csv(
>                         d,
>                         dtype = 'str',
>                         usecols=[
>                             'Owner First Name',
>                             'Owner Last Name',
>                             'StreetNumber',
>                             'StreetName',
>                             'State',
>                             'Zip Code',
>                             'Bdrms',
>                             'Legal Description',
>                             'Sq Ftg',
>                             'Address',
>                             'Orig Ln Amt',
>                             'Prop Value'
>                         ],
>
>                         names=[
>                             'Owner_FirstName',
>                             'Owner_LastName',
>                             'StreetNumber',
>                             'StreetName',
>                             'State',
>                             'ZipCode',
>                             'Bdrms',
>                             'Legal_Description',
>                             'Sq_Ftg',
>                             'Address',
>                             'Orig_Ln_Amt',
>                             'Prop_Value'
>                         ],
>                         skipinitialspace=True
>                     )
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with your existing options you can use engine as python and provide the separator like whitespaces (\s) and tabs with (\t) in the sep arg.

```
pd.read_csv(engine='python', sep='\s+|,|\t')
```